# Copy range of data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 every day as a log

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 in the same workbook. The data set needs to be copied from range C3 to C7 on sheet 1 to B3 to F3 on sheet 2. The data gets copied everyday on sheet 2 as a log. I have a code that works if I define a single cell with Range object but doesn't work with multiple cells.

The code is inserted on a button. Please find below the code. I'm a novice and would appreciate if someone helps with the error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim Data As String
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Data = Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(3, 7))
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(6, 3)).Select

    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(6, 3)).Offset(1, 0)<> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(6, 3)).End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Data
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(3, 7)).Select

End Sub

Private Sub Update_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the Range("C3:C7") from "Sheet1" to Range("B3:F3") in "Sheet2" , you can use the code below (without using `Select` and `ActiveCell`).

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()    

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:C7").Copy     
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

**Note**: this will result with "overwriting" the previous date's data, and will be hard to use it as a log.

You can use the code below, to paste it in the first empty row in Column B in "Sheet2":

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:C7").Copy            

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1 '<-- find first empty row in column B        
        .Range("B" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai for the quick response! The first part of the code works fine but the second part is giving  compilation error that says: "Ambiguous name detected." Can you please tell me how I can work this out?

Comment: @ArnabD on which line do you get the error ? where does the ywllow line stands ?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. I'm sorry I copy-pasted both codes and as a result the error occurred. Thanks a bunch again for your help @Shai. :)